# I need to access a random .txt file, or a random line of a .txt file and out put it to the screen

Tags: c++, random, char

What I am trying to do is create a (seemingly) random fact generator, by selecting a random .txt file, containing the fact, and outputting it to the screen.  Here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "getQuestion.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int mainMenuChoice;
    ifstream Bibliography;
    //string easyBib;
    char randomQuestion;
    string easyBib;
    string Questions /*[15]*/;
    string Answers /*[15]*/;
    ifstream inputFile;
    //char newline = '\n';
    //char chars;
    //int linenum = 1;
    string line;
    char randomQ;


    //cout << "%s by Noah" << endl;
    cout << "Quiz Menu\n\n";
    cout << "1. Play Game!\n";
    cout << "2. Bibliography\n";
    cout << "3. Developer Info\n";
    //cout << "4. Admin Menu\n";
    cout << "4. Exit\n";
    cout << "Menu Choice: ";
    cin >> mainMenuChoice;

    switch (mainMenuChoice) {
    case 1: {
        srand ( time(NULL) );

        randomQuestion = rand() % 10 + 1;



        randomQ = '0' + randomQuestion;

        randomQ = randomQ + '.txt';

        inputFile.open(randomQ);

        getline(inputFile, line);

        vector<string> lines;
        for( string line; getline(inputFile,line); )
        {
            lines.push_back(line);
        }

        size_t iRandLine = rand() % lines.size();
        string randomLine = lines[iRandLine];
        cout << "Line " << (iRandLine+1) << ": " << randomLine << endl;

        break;
            }
    case 2: {
        inputFile.open("Bib.txt");
        //istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char \n )
        inputFile >> easyBib;
        cout << easyBib << endl;;

        return(0);
            }
    case 3: {
        cout << "Program made by: XXXX XXXXXXXX" << endl;
        cout << "Mrs. XXXXXXX's Period 4 Social Studies Class" << endl;
        break;
            }
    case 4: {
        cout << "Thank you for playing!" << endl;
        return(0);
            }
    default: {
        cout << "Sorry, Invalid Choice!\n";
        return(2);
             }

    }
    return(0);
}
```

i am also getting this compiler error:

```
52: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
52: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
```

Thank you so much everyone.

If it is applicable I am using XCode 3.2.6, and Mac OS X 10.6.8
Please don't ask me to upgrade or download anything, it is a school laptop, and I don't have sudo privileges.

Comment: You should make randomQ a 'std::string' ;) All your operations don't work with char, esp. not with a single char.

Comment: Wow, I just saw that. `randomQ = randomQ + '.txt.';` will definitely NOT work the way you want it to.

Comment: To elaborate, randomQ is declared as "char", which means it holds exactly one character. You can't assign a string to it. Even if you could, a literal with single quotes like '.txt' is a char; you need double quotes like this: ".txt"

Comment: Lots of problems with this. For one, `randomQuestion` is a char, same with `randomQ`. `randomQ = '0' + randomQuestion;` is basically `48 + some_random_number`, and you'll get a character instead of 05 or 03 or 08 whatever. Then with the line `randomQ + '.txt';`, if you're trying to append a number to the string ".txt", you should be using double quotes around ".txt" and not single quotes

Answer (score 1):

If you know any scripting languages like Python or Perl, you should probably use those instead of C++ for what you're trying to do; they have much more intuitive facilities for what you want to do, and the syntax is much cleaner.

If you're gonna stick with C++, this is what you might consider;

- Place every text file inside a folder (let's call it `questions`), and sets its filename to an integer (no extension).
- Generate an integer randomly, possibly with a maximum value (depending on how you're numbering these questions).
- If there exists a file in `questions` named for that integer (i.e. if you draw 41, then if `./questions/41` exists), use it.  If not, draw again.

By the way, you wouldn't happen to go to high school on Long Island, would you?  If so, I think we might have gone to the same school (though I graduated).

Comment: This project is due Tuesday, and I'm just learning Python; so it is to late to switch to that, and this project is for history, not programming (it was by choice to do a program).  Wouldn't the compiler automatically look for a const char instead of an int for the `inputFile.open(var);`

Comment: Then cast that int to a char with, if I recall, static_cast<char>(your_int), or use stringstreams if you know how (if not, they're easy).

Comment: If you used this, would you mind marking this as your preferred answer?  Standard practice on Stack Overflow.  Thank you.